# Dónde cambiar como aparece el nombre de mi sitio web en los resultados de busqueda de google?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

Quisiera saber de que manera puedo cabiar el bustitulo que trae por defecto la indexacion de google a las paginas webs, dejo una imagen de referencia, mi pagina web es la que esta marcada en rojo y adentro de ella esta subrayado lo que estoy preguntando, acomparacion de las dos que estan arriba y abajo asi quiero que se vea  la mia y que no salga con la url como las de ejemplo no se si me hice entender, en google search vi que se podia pero ya no esta la opcion de cambiarlo, algun otro metodo?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<head>   <meta charset="UTF-8">   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
content="IE=edge">   <meta name="viewport"
content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   <meta
name="description" content="Página oficial del acueducto y
alcantarillado (Corregimiento ayacucho la buitrera palmira)
                                    Para mayor información, oficina: Corregiduria La Buitrera - Codigo postal 763538">   <!-- Title -->    
<title>Acueducto de la buitrera palmira</title>

  <!-- Favicon -->     <link rel="icon"
href="/Assets/ICONOS/Favicon/favicon.ico">

  <!-- Font-Awesome (CSS) -->   <link rel="stylesheet"
href="/Assets/VENDORS/Font_awesome/css/all.css">

  <!-- Magnific-Popup (CSS) -->   <link rel="stylesheet"
href="/Assets/VENDORS/Magnific_popup/magnific-popup.css">

  <!-- Swiper (CSS) -->   <link rel="stylesheet"
href="/Assets/VENDORS/Swiper/Swiper.css">

  <!-- Custom Stylesheets -->   <link rel="stylesheet"
href="/Assets/CSS/Main.css">   <link rel="stylesheet"
href="/Assets/CSS/Responsive.css">

</head>
```

Comment: Muestra tu código html desde <head> hasta </head>

Comment: Ya lo puse en la publicacion

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, pero deberías ver esta página https://gist.github.com/whitingx/3840905

Answer (score 0):

Según Google, esto lo detectan automáticamente en ciertos modos. De todos modos, si no tienes tu sitio en Search Console, deberías añadirlo ya que te dará cierta información sobre cómo Google lo detecta.

Además, según la [documentación de Google Search](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/site-names?hl=es), puedes usar datos estructurados y OpenGraph para declarar estas cosas, más allá de lo que detecta con el `<title>` (en este caso incorrectamente) o por el contenido del `<h1>` de la página.

Lo más sencillo sería añadir esto a la página principal (`https://acueductolabuitrerapalmira.com.co/`):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context" : "https://schema.org",
    "@type" : "WebSite",
    "name" : "Mi sitio web",
    "url" : "https://acueductolabuitrerapalmira.com.co/"
}
</script>
```

Finalmente, también puedes añadir los metadatos [OpenGraph](https://ogp.me/), que también mejorarán como se muestra el sitio web al compartirlo en redes sociales como Facebook, Twitter o Mastodon.

Comment: Ah bueno gracias bro lo voy a probar